# SQL 3 joins with group by and sum function

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables 
Tbcodetable

```
    codevalue | codename | desc1 | desc2 
    1         | SATO     | NAG   | Naga
    2         | SATO     | BAG   | Baguio
    3         | SATO     | NCR   | Head Office
```

Tbmember

```
employeeno | capcon_accountno | savings_accountno | sato
1          | 00101            | 00201             | NCR
2          | 00102            | 00202             | BAG
```

Tbdeposit

```
employeeno | account_no | accountbalance
1          | 00101      | 1000
1          | 00201      | 5000
2          | 00102      | 1000
2          | 00202      | 5000
```

What I want to query is sum of capital and savings per sato in one query

```
codename | codevalue | desc1      | desc2 | capcon | savings
SATO     |3          |Head Office |NCR    |1000    | 5000
SATO     |2          |Baguio      |BAG    |1000    | 5000
SATO     |1          |Naga        |NAG    |0       | 0
```

The best query I could do is

```
SELECT codename,codevalue,desc1,desc2,sum(b.accountbalance) as capcon 
  FROM TBCODETABLE c 
  left join TBMEMBER a on c.desc2 = a.SatoCode 
  join tbdeposit b on a.employeeno = b.employeeno 
 where a.SLAStatus = 'A' and c.codename ='sato'
group by codename, codevalue, desc1, desc2
```

which gives me this result

```
codename | codevalue | desc1      | desc2 | capcon
SATO     |1          |Head Office |NCR    |1000
SATO     |2          |Baguio      |BAG    |1000
```

This only gives me the sum of capital(Im lost on how include both savings and capital on result.) and it doesnt include the naga region

I could join tbmember and tbdeposit by employeeno but then I dont know how to separate sum of capital and savings in the result set

**Edit**
 I edited the query and now Im able to query both thanks to syed but I still cant get the NAG sato code.
**Query:**

```
SELECT codename,codevalue,desc1,desc2, coalesce(sum(b.accountbalance),0) as savings, coalesce(sum(bb.accountbalance),0) as capcon FROM TBCODETABLE c left join TBMEMBER a on c.desc2 = a.SatoCode join tbdeposit b on a.SAVINGS_AccountNo = b.AccountNo 
inner join tbdeposit bb on a.CAPCON_Accountno = bb.AccountNo where a.SLAStatus = 'A'
group by codename, codevalue, desc1, desc2
```

I am able to get the expected result thank you guys chris's left join advice solved my NAG SATO problem though Syed's reply helped me big time.
I dont how to upvote a reply so i'll just upvote chris(first time here.)

My final query is :

```
SELECT codename,codevalue,desc1,desc2, coalesce(sum(b.accountbalance),0) as savings, coalesce(sum(bb.accountbalance),0) as capcon FROM TBCODETABLE c left join TBMEMBER a on c.desc2 = a.SatoCode left join tbdeposit b on a.SAVINGS_AccountNo = b.AccountNo 
left join tbdeposit bb on a.CAPCON_Accountno = bb.AccountNo where a.SLAStatus = 'A' or codename = 'sato'
group by codename, codevalue, desc1, desc2
```

Comment: In `Tbcodetable` you have *`codevalue` 1 is Naga* and *`codevalue` 3 is Head Office* but in resulting table it is vice versa.

Comment: And, BTW, why do you need grouping here? IMHO, you just need to join `Tbdeposit` twice. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a7613/8)

Comment: Yeah I just realized I needed just 1 more join as the link @SyedMZulqarnain said. Though it still doesnt get the NAG sato in the result

Comment: @PetSerAl Sorry just a typo in codevalues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you join something against a table you `LEFT JOIN`ed you need to make that also a `left join` because otherwise you end up with something that is an inner join equivalent instead.   That is not your only problem.

Second, for value comparison, case matters so you should have `c.codename ='SATO'` if your table sample is correct.

Third, you probably at that point, want to add a case statement inside your `SUM` so:

```
SUM(case 
    when account_no = capcon_account_no 
    THEN accountbalance ELSE NULL END)
```

You can do something similar then for your savings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a group by `employeeno` and `account_no` in a subquery.  Then split capcon and savings into separate columns with a `case when`:

```
select codename,
       codevalue,
       desc1,
       desc2,
       sum( case when a.savings_accountno = b.account_no then accountbalance else 0 end ) as savings,
       sum( case when a.capcon_accountno = b.account_no then accountbalance else 0 end ) as capcon
from   tbcodetable as c
       left join
       tbmember as a
       on c.desc1 = a.sato
       left join
       (
         select employeeno,
                account_no,
                sum( accountbalance ) as accountbalance
         from   tbdeposit
         group by employeeno,
                account_no
       ) as b
       on a.employeeno = b.employeeno
 group by codename,
       codevalue,
       desc1,
       desc2
```

See SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/497453/10)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select codename,codevalue,desc1,desc2,coalesce(sum(accountbalance),0) as capcon,
coalesce(deposite,0) as saving 
from tbcodetable tc  
left join tbmember tb 
on tc.codevalue = tb.employeeno  
left join(select max(employeeno) as employee,max(accountbalance) as deposite,accountbalance,employeeno from tbdeposite tp group by employeeno)l 
on tb.employeeno = l.employeeno group by codevalue;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7778/1)